# Android - Toast message for Items chosen

Tags: java, android, android-toast

How can I display a `Toast` messages for the items I've chosen in my layout?

For example, I have 15 `ImageView`s that are `selectable`, for example I've selected `ImageView`s 1, 2 and 3. A toast will appear when I click a `button`, "You've chosen `ImageView`s 1, 2, 3."

By the way, I've used `setTag` to know when an `ImageView` is selected. I've setup `setTag("1")` for the views that is selected and `setTag("0")` for the rest.

Sample code that I've tried:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String message = "You've chosen";
        if (v.getTag().toString().equals("1")) {
            message = message + " " + ivCircles[i].getId();
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Use a HashSet int your Adapter to store the item num which you have selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line should be in `onClick` method of `ImageView`

```
message = message + " " + view.getId();
```

This line should be a global variable

```
public static String message = "You've chosen";
```

After toast displayed in onClick method of the button, the global varibale should be initiated again

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
message = "You've chosen";
```

Answer (score 0):

set contentDescription for each image & after selecting one of the image get content discription

```
Toast.makeText(context,imageview.getContentDiscription(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Can you explain further @yuva? I am a total newb in Android and Java. I jumped in directly not knowing anything but If you can explain it further I will be able to understand it.

Comment: Okay mate. Give me a minute

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [ActionMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout lnrItems;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lnrItems = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrItems);

        for (int i=1;i<=15;i++){
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setId(i);
            imageView.setTag(String.valueOf(i));
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You've chosen ImageViews "+v.getTag().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            lnrItems.addView(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try it @Haresh, and will mark check if its solved my problem